# Making screenshot of Google Map bigger than my device screen

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an Android application which is using Google Maps API v2 and is sharing the map screen through socket connection with another Android device. It all works fine but I want to make it taking a screenshot of a map which is bigger than the map on my screen so that it can fit perfectly on the bigger screen of the device which is receiving the screenshots. For example: My app screen is 540x719 and the bitmap which the 2nd device receives is with width: 540 and height: 719. How can I make it sent screenshots which fit perfectly to the second application?

The method which I use for screenshots of Google Map:

```
public void CaptureMapScreen() {
    SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
        Bitmap bitmap1;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        @Override
        public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
            bitmap1 = snapshot;

                try {
                    //some code
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    };
    mGoogleMap.snapshot(callback);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems impossible to me to make an actual **screenshot** of something that is not on the screen. This is because of the simple fact that a "screenshot" **captures the screen**, and **not, what is not on it**.

Also, it is not possible to make an actual screenshot with a higher resolution than the capturing devices screen.

If you are not worried that much about resolution, you could try to **programatically zoom out** your map, then take the screenshot and then zoom back in again. In that way you can capture more of the map.

Another thing you could do is **capture multiple different parts of the map** and later **merge them** to make a single `Bitmap` out of them.